# Using multiple radio buttons to filter ng-repeat boolean object properties

Tags: angularjs

I have json data array of Carpet objects ([see plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sBSjzdcNNAa14SgATsHZ?p=preview))

```
  designerApp.controller('CarpetCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.carpetList = 
  [
    {
      "Carpet": {
          "name": "red carpet",
          "standard": true,
          "wide": false,
          "extra_wide": true
      },
    },
    {
      "Carpet": {
          "name": "blue carpet",
          "standard": false,
          "wide": true,
          "extra_wide": true
      },
    },
    {
      "Carpet": {
          "name": "green carpet",
          "standard": true,
          "wide": true,
          "extra_wide": false
      },
    }
  ];
```

}]);

I want to use radio buttons to filter the list - buttons for standard, wide and extra_wide to filter the respective boolean values.

I have scoured the internet and cannot find anyone else doing this. Can angular handle this natively?

NB The reason each array element is keyed on Carpet is because I have cut down the data pumped out from CakePHP - there is other keyed data in each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZCwlMO5WEOxQvpE9svkR?p=preview).

This is what I changed:

```
  <div class="carpet_list" ng-controller="CarpetCtrl">
    <label>Standard Width<input type="radio" name="width" ng-model="type" value='standard' ></label>
    <label>Wide<input type="radio" name="width" ng-model="type" value='wide' ></label>
    <label>Extra Wide<input type="radio" name="width" ng-model="type" value='extra_wide'></label>
    <br>
    <br>
    {{type}}
  <h2>Carpet List</h2>  
    <ul class="thumblist">
      <li class="thumb" ng-repeat="item in carpetList">
      <label ng-show="item.Carpet[type]">{{item.Carpet.name}}</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

As you can see the idea is to show the carpets with 'type' true.

Comment: Thank you! It was driving me nuts. Weird thing is I'm just up the road from Camden - I shop in Morrisons!

Comment: @PGTips Glad to be of help to a fellow Camden resident. If you're interested in AngularJS you might want to check out these MeetUp groups http://www.meetup.com/AngularJS-London, http://www.meetup.com/AngularJS-London-BYOP/

Comment: Cool - I'll checck it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OixpOnfqr4hqlUgylhYB?p=preview)

The radios model is a single variable containing the type of carpet to display

```
$scope.filters = {
  width: 'standard'
};
```

Then you display only the element on which this property is true.

```
<li class="thumb" ng-repeat="item in carpetList" ng-show="item.Carpet[filters.width]">
```

There's probably a "cleaner" way with filters, but apparently you can't filter a single item, you have to filter the whole array

Comment: Thanks for your input -I'm an Angular noob. I think @camden_kid did it more cleanly.